# pivot "stacked" data with multiple indexes?

Tags: pandas

I have some "stacked" or "record format" data that looks like this (coming from the database):

```
"recid","code","value","exam_num"  
"101703034","k_rat1","17/18","1"  
"200907062","e_mas1","AC YES","6"  
"203004134","k_rat1","5/18","5"  
"303505091","k_gtrdsc","Foo","1"  
"303505091","k_rat1","4/18","2"
```

And i want to pivot it to look like this:

```
recid,exam_num,k_rat1,e_mas1,k_gtrdsc
101703034,1,"17/18",,
200907062,6,,"AC YES",
203004134,5,"5/18",,
303505091,1,,,Foo
303505091,2,"4.18",,
```

I can make it work with just the one index (recid) like this:

```
my_df = read_csv("data.csv")
pivoted = my_df.pivot(index="recid",columns="code",values="value")
```

Which gives me this (note the missing exam_num column):

```
recid,e_mas1,k_gtrdsc,k_rat1
101703034,,,17/18
200907062,AC YES,,
203004134,,,5/18
303505091,,Foo,4/18
```

However, when i try to specify multiple indexes, or most anything else, i get various errors. I have read this: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reshaping.html, but couldn't see a way to do exactly what i'm after.

Help would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set your multilevel index and then [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) the level within that index back to columns:

```
pivoted = my_df.set_index(['recid', 'exam_num', 'code']).unstack('code')
```

Comment: Sorry, it's not clear to me how i should set my multi-level index. Can you elaborate? When i run you code after read_csv, it doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: assign the result to a variable and look at the result

Comment: I wasn't very clear. I am outputting the result to a CSV file, and it is essentially identical to the input CSV file:

    `my_df = read_csv("data.csv")` 
    `my_df.set_index(['recid', 'exam_num', 'code']).unstack('code')` 
    `my_df.to_csv("out.csv")`

Comment: transformations of the dataframe are not inplace. assign the instruction to a variable, like `pivoted`, and do `pivoted.to_csv("out.csv")`

Comment: fantastic! This is what i want, but can i have the column headers be just "e_mas1..." instead of "('value', 'e_mas1')..."